# Choose first or last rows depending on boolean

Tags: python, pandas, slice

The dataframe below is sorted by column `a`, and the script checks if the first `30%` rows for column `b` are `NaN`. If they are, `and` the rest of the rows are not all `NaN`, then we print `True`. If I want to check whether the final rows are `NaN` instead of the first rows, then I set `beginning_data=False`. I'm wondering if there's any better pythonic way to accomplish this, without using `if/else`?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a' : [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], 'b' : [pd.NA,pd.NA,pd.NA,8,5,6,7,8,1,2]})
pct_rows = 0.3
nr_rows = int(df.shape[0] * pct_rows)
beginning_data = True
if beginning_data:
    pct_rows_null = df['b'].iloc[:nr_rows].isna().all()
    rest_rows = df['b'].iloc[nr_rows:].notna().all()
else:
    pct_rows_null = df['b'].iloc[-nr_rows:].isna().all()
    rest_rows = df['b'].iloc[:-nr_rows].notna().all()

print((pct_rows_null & rest_rows))
```

Comment: just a small nit, but i would change the ilocs to `head(nr_rows)` and `tail(nr_rows)`

Comment: also this might be good for https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can use np.where here ->

```
pct_rows = 0.3
nr_rows = int(df.shape[0] * pct_rows)

beigining = np.where((df['b'].iloc[:nr_rows].isna().all()) & (df['b'].iloc[nr_rows:].notna().all()),True, False)
end  = np.where((df['b'].iloc[-nr_rows:].isna().all()) & (df['b'].iloc[:-nr_rows].notna().all()),True, False)
```

**Output-**

```
print(beigining,end) # True False
```

**Via np.select -**

```
pct_rows = 0.3
nr_rows = int(df.shape[0] * pct_rows)

condlist = [
    (df['b'].iloc[:nr_rows].isna().all()) & (df['b'].iloc[nr_rows:].notna().all()),
    (df['b'].iloc[-nr_rows:].isna().all()) & (df['b'].iloc[:-nr_rows].notna().all())
]
choiselist = [
    'True',
    'False'
]
np.select(condlist,choiselist)
```

I guess you want this (Return True if both conditions are True else False)->

```
cond1 = (df['b'].iloc[:nr_rows].isna().all()) & (df['b'].iloc[nr_rows:].notna().all())
cond2 = (df['b'].iloc[-nr_rows:].isna().all()) & (df['b'].iloc[:-nr_rows].notna().all())
np.where((cond1 & cond2), True, False)
```

Comment: hey! i only want either true or false, not both true and false as output. you had an answer before using `select` which seemed to do  what i wanted

Comment: thanks! i'll probably use the one with `np.select(condlist, choice)`, where i can put `choice = [beginning, ~beginning]`. since i only want one of the conditions based on the boolean `beginning`